# How do I type an accented letter in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot find anything remotely resembling instructions for typing an accented character in VSCode.

Comment: Which platform are you working on? Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, entering special characters (including letters with accents) can be done with [ALT Codes](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/windows/codealt/). Pressing down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and then a specific series of numbers on the num pad will type the corresponding character.

*e.g.*

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0233</kbd> = é
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0225</kbd> = á

On OSX, the method is a bit simpler: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201586

Typing special characters on Linux is [a bit hairy...](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Accented_Characters)

Comment: @DieLaughing Please upvote and or accept my answer if it works for you. If not, let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: It does not work. I'm using Linux, of course. Your link regarding Linux being "a bit hairy..." was not enlightening at all, sorry.

Comment: @DieLaughing Well just saying that won't help me ***at all***. What distro are you running?

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 18. Apparently I have to use Control+Shift+u and then type the unicode hex value of the character I want. Sub-optimal for sure. Thanks for your assistance, it was appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome for the help I was able to give. Good luck!

Comment: @itconfig e acute is ALT 0 2 3 3 (on the numeric keypad) on Windows: the leading 0 is important.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**Insert Unicode**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brunnerh.insert-unicode) plugin.

To type '`É`'
(which is not easy to get, even on a French keyboard, unless you remember <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0201</kbd>):

- simply type `E` (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>)
- then "Insert Unicode" (through the palette command), and select `0x301 COMBINNING ACUTE ACCENT`

You can easily define keyboard shortcut to insert your favorite emoji

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+e f",
    "command": "insert-unicode.insertTextExact",
    "args": "fire"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tape in command-line setxkbmap fr , and tape 2 for é , 0 for à and 7 for è

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you don't type often, you can follow the guide below and just copy and past the accented characters into VSCode.

On a Mac: Press Option+N, then type the letter you want to accent.
On a Windows PC: Enable Num Lock, press and hold Alt, then type the character's specific number code (see below).
iOS or Android device: Press and hold the A, N, or O key on the virtual keyboard, then select the tilde option.

Answer (score 0):

I present a slightly inelegant (alright, brutish) solution. Since I type a lot of *Gaelic* lately, I simply pasted the string "**ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòù**" as a comment at the bottom of my document. This keeps it in close proximity to the current text and is a few keystrokes shy of my previous solution of alt-tabbing to another editor. I might investigate defining keystrokes along the lines of alt+vowel and shift+alt+vowel…